# ScrollViewer not working with ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I'm trying to use a `ScrollViewer` to be able to scroll the items in an `ItemsControl` but for some reason, it's not working. The scroll view shows but it is disabled.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tool.Views.ShortcutsView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            d:DesignWidth="500"
            mc:Ignorable="d" Height="541">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GlobalShortcutButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> 
     <!-- Style code -->
 </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid Margin="10,40,10,0" Background="White" Height="108" VerticalAlignment="Top">


            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">        
                <ItemsControl 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutsObservableCollection}" 
                        Height="108" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button 
                                    Height="35" 
                                    Content="{Binding ShortcutName}" 
                                    Command="{Binding ShortcutCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}" 
                                    Margin="10 0 0 10"
                                    Background="#FF30CCFF" 
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Padding="10,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>


        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is what I see...

[image]

There are plenty of items in the `ItemsControl` for the scroller to show and be able to scroll the items in it, the rest of the items are hidden.

Any idea what can I do to make the scroller to show up properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove Height="108" from your ItemsControl. You can't scroll because there is nothing to scroll.